# How should I trace/vectorize my logo?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, cs5, image-trace

[image: Illustrator screenshot]

First of all I would like to say that I'm new to AI and PS, therefore there's probably lots of things I'm not doing right. I am using CS5 version.

I have a logo that is mainly black and white, but because of the grays, I couldn't trace it automatically.
So, instead, I made the path with the pen tool.
The problem is that now I have the path separated from the original image instead of what I really want. Which is the original logo with the path so I can have everything that is white transparent.

I also tried in PS to change the white to other colour (so then I could easily change it to transparent), but I couldn't because some grays also change.

What is the best way to trace/ vectorize my logo?

This is the logo I got[image]

Comment: Indeed, auto trace is rarely a good idea for logos and almost never produces clean results for fonts. Using the pen tool is the way to go (combined with searching for those fonts). However, I'm confused by this: "_The problem is that now I have the path separated from the original image instead of what I really want. Which is the original logo with the path so I can have everything that is white transparent._" Are you trying to create a vector version of the logo or just create a clipping mask  on top of the raster image to hide the white?

Comment: Do you know the fonts that were used with the logo?

Comment: Hi JohnB and AndrewH, I have no idea which fonts were used.
I am trying to create a vector version of the logo, but I needed it to be exactly as it is...
I've mentioned the colour because in this particular case what I need is to change the colour.

Comment: Can you upload the highest res picture of the logo without the logo being selected?

Comment: I think the dg is Linotype Didot font. I think ARTES & DA CULTURA are both Cabin Regular font. I was not able to find the other fonts. The object part of the logo can be traced but I am not sure how you would do the inner part. Very hard to tell exactly what shapes are being used. I would go to whatthefont forum to find the rest of the fonts.

Comment: as others have stated, autotrace isn't the right tool for this. Ideally, you'd redraw the logo and re-set the type with the original typeface. Barring that, you're best of doing a manual re-draw trace rather than using the automated tools.

Comment: If you're hired to design* something with legal purposes for this institution, then it should provide you with the original (.ai, .psd) or at least a high quality file with the logos, maybe jpg or png. If you are doing this for a personal use no mattering if it's wrong or right, you can search for at least, i believe, the "Governo de Portugal" logo file in http://www.brandsoftheworld.com.
And for the others, you can search a font by an image with the tool MyFonts.com provides: http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/. I hope this answer is useful for you. :)

Answer (score 5):

**Never** assume the logo file you are given by *any* client is the "best" they have. This is *especially* true if the file is a raster image. If the client does *not* provide a vector version of their logo, the chances that there are higher quality *raster* images on the web are generally pretty good.

In this case, a quick google reverse image search finds a *much* larger version of those logos.....

[image]

Using Illustrator's Image trace on that larger version yields **much better** results.

[image]

This would still require some minor clean up, but it would circumvent the need to redraw most parts.

While redrawing will almost always provide the best results, in some cases tracing a *large* raster image can be sufficient depending upon your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Doing the trace with a better image showed great improvements.
Now I just need get the autotrace doing it correctly (getting the values). =)

Comment: Setting the color mode of Image Trace to "Greyscale" seemed to work just fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

As Scott said, never assume that's the best there is. Someone, somewhere has the clean art.

My favorite way to try to find vector art is to search for the company name and PDF. So in this case, search for "Governo de Portugal PDF".

Almost every time, I can find a newsletter or something that the designer exported the PDF with a vector logo in it. You can then open the PDF in Illustrator and pick out the logo from the document.

In the case of this logo I found the PDF of their brand guidelines (jackpot!) here: http://www.promar.gov.pt/Download/Beneficiarios/Normas_Graficas_MAM.pdf

If you download the PDF, Page 11 has the vector art in Black & White. Page 19 lists the fonts to use for the Secretario part.

And here is the vector art for dgARTES: http://www.naodamores.com/marcos/Dosier%20Danza/marcos%20de%20contenido/IMAGENES/Logos/CORNUCOPIA.%20PATROCINIOS/logo_dgartes_vertical.pdf